# What's virtual proxy?

Tags: c#, java, design-patterns

According to www.dofactory.com and www.blackwasp.com, a virtual proxy is used to present a simplified version of a complex object. Only when the detail of the object is required,the main object actually is populated, providing a form of lazy loading. Does it mean whenever use use lazy loading, we can call it virtual proxy ? Is there other reasons why we should use it except when we use expensive object? I don't see it vividly. Can someone give a good explanation on it , please ?

Comment: I would say that good uses of virtual proxies is pretty rare.  Most proxies are not virtual or caching partly due to the complexity such a strategy adds.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Have you ever implemented data mappers and lazy load? With data mappers you actually never make use of lazy load?

Comment: I have implemented both with and without virtual proxies.  I tend to use generated code these days for production code instead of proxies. Conversely I tend to use virtual proxies (via mocking libraries) for testing.  Virtual proxies are less effort.

Answer (score 2):

I've never felt the need to do it, but you *can* use Virtual Proxies to [lazily initialize expensive object graphs](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/04/ComposeObjectGraphsWithConfidence.aspx). However, you should very rarely need to do this.

Comment: This means that you have never used lazy load? You always get the complete object graph from data mappers (only with the data needed)?

Comment: Lazy loading leads to N+1 issues, so I avoid it. Better to be explicit about what you're fetching.

Comment: For me, sometimes it's faster (or easer) to create some database table joins and then merge it with another select/join (then populate the object). On cases like that, if proxies are implemented, it could avoid the second query merging, since it already exists in the proxy (the relationship that is performed on a separated query). Have you ever thought about that scenario? In this case, there isn't any issue, since the query separation is exactly due to performance and response time. It also worth as a way to test before going deep with the queries like @PeterLawrey said above (quest.comment).